# A rod in empty space

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I imagine a rod in empty space. It has no momentum and it is not rotating. Now, suppose I hit the rod at one end. The rod starts to rotate. And, according to the definition of centre of mass, CM must move as if the force is applied on CM. But, if this is true, then it has both translational and rotational Kinetic energy.

Now, if I apply the force on CM of the rod, then it only has translational KE.

In the above two cases, energies are different. Why is that?!

[image]
([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Force_and_couple.PNG))

I got this picture from wikipedia. It said that both cases shown in the picture are same. In the first case, we have only a single force, but in the second, I have both the force and a couple. Isn't the conservation of energy violated?

Comment: You applied the force at different points, so the result is different. I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for here

Comment: Doesn't it violate energy conservation?

Comment: can you specify how the force is applied, in the question? The confusion results from "a force is applied", but if you define a method, then the answer will be clear.

Comment: Conservation of energy has nothing to do with it. You are looking at two different systems and you assume that they have the same energy. Conservation of energy is about one system in two different situations, two different moments etc. So you have no energy conservation reason to expect the two energies to be the same. It is still interesting to understand the difference between the two cases. But leave conservation alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in the amount of work you do comes down to the difference in displacement, which depends on exactly how the force is applied. If you don't think very carefully about how the force is applied in each situation it's easy for things to get confusing.

The change in the translational kinetic energy is $\Delta K_{trans.} = \int \vec{F}_{net} \cdot d\vec{x}_{CM}$. The change in rotational kinetic energy is $\Delta K_{rot} = \int \tau \,d\theta = \int |\vec{F}_{net}| \sin(\phi_{rF}) \,rd\theta$ where $r$ is the distance from the CM to the point of application of the force and $\phi_{rF}$ tells us about the angle of application of the force.

It helps here to imagine the force happening over a finite amount of time. If you apply a constant force (with constant direction) at the center of mass the object moves a small distance $\Delta x$ so you do work $F\Delta x$. If you try the same thing at a point away from the center of mass the point of application begins to rotate away from you as well as move away from you, so you will end up doing work $F(\Delta x + r\Delta \theta)$. The image below shows how the rotation leads to extra displacement, which means extra work.

[image: An object being pushed at its center of mass versus at a point away from its center of mass, showing the resulting rotation and translation]

There are lots of different ways we could apply the forces in the two different situations. Different methods of application will lead to different motion and hence different amounts of work. Thinking about instantaneous forces kind of hides what's going on, which is why you have to be careful with it.

Comment: So with the same force, I can extract more work by changing the position of application of force

Comment: With the same force and the same displacement you can't. If you push with $F$ for $\Delta x$ on the center of mass you'll get the same amount of energy as if you push with $F$ for $\Delta x$ away from the CM, but in the second case the energy will be split between rotational and kinetic. If you are getting more energy out of the same force it means you are secretly pushing further, even if you don't realize it.

Comment: Forget about forces. Lets say a ball of some momentum hits on the CM and on one end of the rod elastically. Now, is the energy given to the rod same in both cases?

Comment: That doesn't really make things simpler. The amount of energy transferred depends on the force and displacement of the objects while they are in contact. How long they are in contact depends on the masses of the objects and the compressibility of the ball. Unless you specify those things in some way there's no clear cut answer. Ultimately the answer is $\Delta K = F\Delta x_{CM} + \tau \Delta \theta$. What $\Delta x$ and $\Delta \theta$ you get depends on exactly how the forces are applied, and there's no way around that.

Comment: Thanks I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify very carefully what you mean by 'I hit the rod'.

Suppose this means you hit it with a light hammer of a certain mass and velocity, and the collision is elastic and the hammer recoils (other specifications are available). In the first case this makes the rod rotate, in the second case it doesn't, and in both cases the translational momentum of the rod is the momentum imparted by the hammer, so you have translational momentum/velocity/energy in both cases, but rotational only in the first. Which is your apparent paradox.

But the momentum imparted by the hammer is not the same in both cases. It is the difference between the hammer's initial momentum (which is the same, as you've chosen it to be) and its recoil momentum, which isn't. It's harder to make a rod move by pushing at the centre than by pushing at one end, just because pushing at one end can make it rotate.  The recoil velocity of the hammer will be different, greater in the second case, which means there's more momentum transferred but less energy. Contrariwise, in the first case the energy transfer is greater, and that goes into the rotational energy, but the momentum transfer is less.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The same amount of energy is added to the rod in both cases. The only difference, as mentioned by ACuriousMind, is that the energy is applied to different points on the rod.

So if you push the center of mass, all energy will he added in form of translational kinetic energy. If you apply the force to one end of the rod, some of the energy will be in form of rotational kinetic energy, but the translational kinetic energy will be lower (compared to pushing the center of mass).

For example, let's say you add a kinetic energy of $10J$ to the rod by pushing it. If you push the center of mass, you will have $10J$ of translational kinetic energy, but if you push the rod at one side, you might for example have $6J$ of rotational kinetic energy and $4J$ of translational kinetic energy.

The picture you added is indeed very misleading as it suggests that the force $F$ is the same in both cases. If you were to let the lengths of the arrows represent the magnitude of the forces, they would need to be shorter in the second picture, but adding them together would give the same length as in the first case.

So the total kinetic energy will be the same in both cases and is only "split up" into both translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy when pushing the end of the rod.

Comment: Yuo don't know that the same amount of energy is given to the rod in both cases. It depends on the conditions, which are not specified. You don't need to assume that is the same energy, conservation of energy has nothing to say about this. You are looking a two different systems. Conservation of energy is about a system at two different states or at two diferent times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to impart the same amount of force in both cases, then in the first case the kinetic energy imparted is divided between rotation and translation. In the second case, applying the same force in line with the COM, the rod does not rotate as all the force goes to translation, so the translational speed is greater than the translational speed in the first case with some of the force going to translation and some going to rotation. So conservation of energy is maintained.

Comment: "Amount of force" is not a physical quantity. And this is the problem here, you need to specify what is the same and what is not. Is the force applied during same time? Over the same distance? And this assuming that the magnitude of the force is constant during interaction which is not very realistic.

Comment: If the same Newtons are applied for the same amount of time, then the same force is imparted.

Comment: This is called "impulse" and not force or amount of force.

Answer (score 0):

> The rod starts to rotate. And, according to the definition of centre
> of mass, CM must move as if the force is applied on CM.

If the rod is perfectly stiff it will have to be considered as a point, it won't matter where you hit it. A single force cannot cause a rotation.

Forget about the energy because some of it may dissipate in the processs and you'll never account for it. Conservation of energy doesn't apply here. The conservation laws that do apply are the conservation of momentum and the conservation of angular momentum.

First we strike the bar at one of the ends. It causes change in momentum transferred through an impulse. It will not rotate unless it can deform.

[image]

Deformation causes strain and stress.

[image]

And we arrive at what you found at Wiki. The constant $k$ is non-negative but not more than one. It is equal to one when the rod is perfectly stiff and no couple or rotation accurs.

[image]

And some energy put into the rod will dissipate because bending things causes heating and such which cannot be $100\%$ retrieved to do mechanical work.